# Creating a Progress Bar for an email

Tags: html-email

I have created a progress bar which changes by adjusting the width. It looks like this:

[image: Rendering of progress bar]

Progress bar code:

```
<tr>

<td valign="top" class="textContent" style="background-color:#65b9a6;text-    align:center;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:20px;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;" >

100%

</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td valign="top" class="textContent" style="font-                           size:16px;color:#616161;padding-top:10px;" >

</td>

</tr>
```

I really like the look and feel of the progress bar above, but I am looking for a way to adjust the progress of the bar through an API, which I think could be done with the code below as it can be adjusted based on progress such as: https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_progress

Is there a way to incorporate both these codes to create a better progress bar?

Comment: can you please provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: show your code, bro

Comment: Try tagging as html-email to make sure the email dev types get a look at this

Comment: @Jabberwocky thank you and yes I understand. I rewrote the question to see if it makes more sense.  Essentially, I would like to create progress bars for an email to show the status of documents received. However, the current code I am using works by adjusting the width which does not work as when you put the width at 0 the bar does not remove its background colors. One way I thought this could work is through incorporating progress into the code such as: https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_progress

Comment: I don't think this is doable. You could possibly try scrolling magic with background images but even then you'll hit limitations in most email clients. I wouldn't spend too much time on this if you aren't too familiar with the nuances of email client rendering as it's absolutely a rabbit hole to jump through and will take weeks if not months of experimenting and testing to get right.

Comment: @Digital_Frankenstein, thank you so much and sounds good. Agreed, I will focus on the other elements of the email.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're asking. If you want to modify the progress bar as result of an action, you can run this JavaScript code every time you want to update the progress:

```
document.getElementById("elementName").style.width = "100";
```

(In which `elementName` is the name of the ID assigned to the green portion, and `"100"` is the width of the progress bar)

If you have text, you can update it like so:

```
document.getElementById("elementName").innerHTML = "Text";
```

(In which `elementName` is the name of the ID assigned to the text element, and `"Text"` is the text you want it to display)

If you use the `progress` element, you can update it like this:

```
document.getElementById("elementName").value = "100";
```

(In which `elementName` is the name of the id assigned to the `progress` element, and `"100"` is the amount completed in relation to the `max` value assigned in your HTML.)

If you want it to be a static animation that fills up over a static amount of time, you can animate it using CSS:

```
#elementName {
    animation: progressFill 1s;
}

@keyframes progressFill {
    from {width: 0%;}
    to {width: 100%;}
}
```

(In which `#elementName` is the name of the id assigned to the green portion, `progressFill` is the desired name for the animation, and `1s` is the length of the animation. This is, of course, assuming that `width: 0%;` and `width: 100%;` provide the desired results.)

I hope this helps.

Comment: OP was asking about progress bar in an email. Javascripts dont work in emails.